# Prove that the covariance between a random variable and an indicator on its value is negative

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, covariance

Say that $X$ is a random variable with a known mean. We define $I$ to be the variable $I=1$ if $X\leq a$ and $I=0$ if $X> a$. How do I prove that their covariance has to be negative?

I begun from the formula for covariance and calculated,
$$
Cov(X,I)=E(XI)-E(X)\mu_X-\mu_IE(X)+\mu_X\mu_I\\
=E(XI)-E(X)P(X\leq a)-E(X)P(X\leq a)+E(X)P(X\leq a)\\
=E(XI)-E(X)P(X\leq a)
$$
I cannot prove that the final statement is negative and that is where I am stuck. Any hints or tips welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first hint would be to use in your last equality, the common equality$$X=X\cdot1_{X\leq a}+X\cdot1_{X> a}$$
where
$$1_{X\leq a}=\begin{cases}1 \text{ if }X\leq a\\0\text{ else }\end{cases}$$
(its your $I$ )and $1_{X> a}$ is defined accordingly.

Edit:
In addition, you can always use this kind of inequality:
$$X\cdot1_{X\leq a}\leq a\cdot1_{X\leq a}$$ and so
$$\mathbb{E}[X\cdot1_{X\leq a}]\leq a\mathbb{P}(X\leq a)$$
Or
$$X\cdot1_{X> a}> a\cdot1_{X> a}$$ and so
$$\mathbb{E}[X\cdot1_{X> a}]> a\mathbb{P}(X> a)$$

(you don't need both in your case)

Comment: sorry I had a mistake in the question now it should be better

Comment: not sure how to use the hint though I am trying to substitute it in as X